# Yolo doesn't use GPU

Tags: python, neural-network, yolo, yolov8

When my nn starts learning, the kernel crashes

```
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell. 

Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. 

Click here for more info. 

View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Yolo doesn't use my GPU resources for learning instead it trying to use CPU and I think that it is a reason why kernel crashes.
How I can fix it?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqpyO.png)

I tried to install CUDA 7.5 (for my RTX 2060). I recently started to study neural networks and I am not sure that I need CUDA.
I also checked similar topics here but I am not sure that there is my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot that I should install PyTorch version with CUDA